Filter Results by Value in Datadog
I'm trying to get a list of EC2 instances with average CPU utilization less than 70%.
So far, I've managed to achieve this with the query avg:aws.ec2.cpuutilization{aws_account:12345678900} by {host} but it shows all hosts in descending order. Is there a way to filter it to show only hosts with under 70% utilization?
If that's possible, can I also combine multiple conditions? For instance, all hosts with average CPU utilization <70% AND utilization spikes over 90%?
